# Setting Buffer Size in GZipStream

Tags: c#, http, proxy, stream, gzip

I was writing a light-weight proxy in c#. When I was decoding the gzip contentEncoding I noted that if I use a small buffer-size(4096) the stream is decoded partially depending the size of the input. Is it a bug in my code or something which is needed to make it work? I set the buffer to 10 MB, and it works okay but defeats my purpose of writing a light-weight proxy.

```
 response = webEx.Response as HttpWebResponse;
 Stream input = response.GetResponseStream();
 //some other operations on response header

 //calling DecompressGzip here


private static string DecompressGzip(Stream input, Encoding e)
    {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream decompressor = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(input, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
           // works okay for [1024*1024*8];
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int n = 0;

                do
                {
                    n = decompressor.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (n > 0)
                    {
                        sb.Append(e.GetString(buffer));
                    }

                } while (n > 0);

        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out. I guess using the string builder causes the problem; instead, I used a memory stream and it works well.

```
private static string DecompressGzip(Stream input, Encoding e)
    {

        using (Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream decompressor = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(input, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {

            int read = 0;
            var buffer = new byte[4096];

            using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while ((read = decompressor.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return e.GetString(output.ToArray());
            }


        }

    }
```